# Adding +1 to variable

Tags: javascript

So the way this code is supposed to work is like this, when I click the button I am going to add +1 to the variable antal and the second time when I press the button it should add another +1 making it 2.

Now the problem is that every time I push the button I instead get another 1 so the second time I have 11 and the third 111 I've tried everything but I cant get it right.

I can understand that there is a simple fix to this but I am quite new, thanks in advance for your answers. =)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uppgift 2</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script Language="JavaScript">
        var antal = 0;
        var $antalClick = {};

        $antalClick.click = function() {
            var antal = Math.round(document.getElementById("antal").value += 1);
        };
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="formone">
        <input type="button" value="resultat" onClick="$antalClick.click ();"/>
        <input type="text" id="antal"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are adding 1 to a string which becomes 'string' + 1

Comment: Data retrieved from HTML input elements is a **STRING**.

Comment: `Math.round(parseInt(document.getElementByID("antal").value, 10) += 1);`...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it is interpreting it as a string. You have to force it to be a number with `parseInt()`

Try

```
Math.round(parseInt(document.getElementById("antal").value) + 1);
```

Comment: Could also use the unary `+` operator.